# Trigger swipe animations without calling a new Activity/Fragment

Tags: android

I want to trigger the default swipe animations on Android when a swipe gesture occurs, without changing the currently displayed Activity.

The point of this is that I want to simulate that the Activity has changed when an important event occurs in my Activity.

The questions I've seen on the Internet all relly on changing the Activity, Fragment, View ,etc.

I wonder if this is possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as far as I know. Google would generally be against allowing such behavior through purely their libraries as it does not follow Android ui patterns.